# How to create a PDF generator on Python?

Tags: python, sdk, pdf-generation

I'm a beginner programmer, tryna teach myself to code. One of the ways I do that is I give myself projects to work on. Right now I'm working on a PDF generator application and my question is where can I start in build this application? I've heard of SDKs and APIs, but I'm not really sure how to use them in my code, whether I have to import a file for it, or something of that sort. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [python-pdfkit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit)

#### Installation

```
pip install pdfkit
```

#### PDF Generation

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')
```

You can pass a list with multiple URLs or files:

```
pdfkit.from_url(['google.com', 'yandex.ru', 'engadget.com'], 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file(['file1.html', 'file2.html'], 'out.pdf')
```

Also you can pass an opened file:

```
with open('file.html') as f:
    pdfkit.from_file(f, 'out.pdf')
```

If you wish to further process generated PDF, you can read it to a variable:

```
# Use False instead of output path to save pdf to a variable
pdf = pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', False)
```

Comment: Yes, for further processing generated PDF

Comment: Yeah, I mean you have created the pdf and stored it in a variable, and further you can highlight some words or do some other things after storing it in some variable. That variable will help to do all these things.

Comment: Why using the method "with open" to load file will cause missing '\n' in pdf file created?

Comment: I don't think it should coz it is still file object.

Comment: I'm tryna figure out how I can input any file into the program so it can be converted into PDF. I tried the input function in order for me to input the file in the terminal and have the program open and read it, but with no luck. I keep getting errors. How can I input the document in the first place so it can be converted. And how can I do this so that I can input any document without having to rewrite my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents, and it does everything for you, so you can focus on the contents of the document.

Check the docs [here](https://pdfme.readthedocs.io/).